# How to show dialog/pop-up on wcf call?

Tags: c#, android, web-services, wcf

I am new in .NET/WCF. I know this is very stupid question but still I want to know that.

Can I show a dialog/pop-up on desktop when I call WCF url from browser or mobile application?

Comment: Why would you want that? If you host the wcf service in a desktop application you can do that, yes. But what's the point?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was expecting

Comment: I'm going to turn my comment into an answer for you to accept.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, please up vote my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you host the wcf service in a desktop application you can do that, yes.